# Changing the min/time of a time selector

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a a date selector and a time selector, I want to change the min/max hours of the time selector depending on what days are selected in the date selector. here is my code:

```
$('#car-rental-pickup-date').pickadate({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    min: tomorrow,
    max: nextyear,
    today: '',
    close: '',
    clear: '',
    disable: [
    1,
  ]


});

$('#car-rental-pickup-time').pickatime({
    clear: '',
    min: [9,00],
    max: [16,30]
});
```

I am sure it follows something like

```
    var dropoff_date = new Date(document.getElementById("car-rental-pickup-date").value);
if ((dropoff_date.getDay() == 6) {
        min: [9,00],
        max: [11,30]
}{
        min: [9,00],
        max: [16,30]
}
```

But I can't get it to function, advise?

Edit: I am using this one: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/

Comment: We'll need to know what jQuery date & time picker components you're using for a start - they all have their own API.

Comment: Also, what does the date/time picker's documentation say about setting options dynamically?

Comment: I am using: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/ - it doesn't really have any documentation about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of what you need is documented in the [API](https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api) section of the docs, but in short you need to:

- subscribe to the `onSet` event on the date picker so you get notified when the date changes
- determine if it is a saturday (you had this).
- Update the `max` time using the `set` method of the time picker.

Ignore all the imports in the snippet below, it is the javascript you need.

```js
const timepicker = $('#car-rental-pickup-time').pickatime({
    clear: '',
    min: [9,00],
    max: [16,30]
});

var datepicker = $('#car-rental-pickup-date').pickadate({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    min: new Date(2019,8,14),
    max: new Date(2020,8,13),
    today: '',
    close: '',
    clear: '',
    disable: [
      1,
    ],
    onSet:function(context){
      var d = new Date(context.select);
      var isSat = d.getDay() == 6;
      var max = isSat ? [11,30] : [16,30];
      var time = timepicker.pickatime('picker');
      time.clear().set({max});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.4/compressed/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.4/compressed/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.4/compressed/picker.time.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.4/compressed/themes/classic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.4/compressed/themes/classic.date.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.6.4/compressed/themes/classic.time.css">
<input type="date" id="car-rental-pickup-date">
<input type="time" id="car-rental-pickup-time">
```

Comment: Nice one @Jamiec!

Comment: Hi Jamiec, could I ask a follow up question on this code... it worked perfectly but my needs have changed slightly and I am having an issue with it...

Comment: @jamiec please check this out, maybe you can advise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003023/change-time-in-day-date-picker-depending-on-location-day

Answer (score -1):

Very less information is provided by you, though you can try below:

You can create a onChange or onBlur event on date fields and then on basis of that you can set the min/max of the time.

Comment: There must be a way to modify the min/max time before opening the box... so the user can't even select it....

Comment: @tony yes when you change the date, then automatically the event associated with the date will be called and the time boundary will be modified by the associated events without opening the time box.